# Laravel how to return a whole item data with the highest value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, backend

How can I return the whole item data, I've used **max** to get the hieghest value but it only returns the value of the field not the whole item

```
public static function getTeamLeaders($competitionId, $teamId) {
        if($teamId){
            $ppg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get()
                    ->max('Points');

            $apg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get()
                    ->max('Assists');

            $fgpg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get()
                    ->max('FieldGoals');

            $data = ['ppg' => $ppg, 'apg' => $apg, 'fgpg' => $fgpg];
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
array:3 [▼
  "ppg" => 15.18
  "apg" => 3.76
  "fgpg" => 12.04
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use orderBy to sort on the field that you want the max of, and then select the first result.

> docs:
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

```
$ppg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                ->orderBy('Points', 'desc')
                ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `max` use `orderBy`

```
self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->orderBy('Points', 'desc')
                    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your code like :

```
public static function getTeamLeaders($competitionId, $teamId) {
        if($teamId){
            $ppg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->whereRaw('Points = (select max(`Points`) from table_name)')
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get();


            $apg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->whereRaw('Assists = (select max(`Assists`) from table_name)')
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get());

            $fgpg = self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
                    ->whereRaw('FieldGoals = (select max(`FieldGoals`) from table_name)')
                    ->where('teamId', $teamId)
                    ->get();

            $data = ['ppg' => $ppg, 'apg' => $apg, 'fgpg' => $fgpg];
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Only change 'max' to 'orderBy'.

```
$something= self::where('competitionId', $competitionId)
            ->where('teamId', $teamId)
            ->orderBy('Points', 'desc')
            ->first();
```